# Vue component over-complication

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vue.js

I'm building a date range selector, and while this works, I feel like I'm making it more complicated than it needs to be. Is there a more elegant way of writing this?

Possibly using computed values or watches?

```
<template>
<form>
    <select  @change="rangeSelection">           
            <option 
                v-for="(option, key) in rangeOptions"
                :key="key"
                :value="key">
                {{option.display}}
            </option>
    </select>
    </form>
</template>

<script>
import moment from 'moment';

export default {
  name: 'DateRangeChooser',
  data: () => {
    return {
        selectedRange: "last7Days",
        startDate: moment().subtract(8, 'days'),
        endDate: moment().subtract(1, 'days'),
        rangeOptions: {
            last7Days: {
                display: 'Last 7 Days',
                startDate: moment().subtract(8, 'days'),
                endDate: moment().subtract(1, 'days')
            },
            lastWeek: {
                display: 'Last Week',
                startDate: moment().startOf('week').subtract(1, 'week'),
                endDate: moment().endOf('week').subtract(1, 'week')
            },
            last30days: {
                display: 'Last 30 days',
                startDate: moment().subtract(31, 'days'),
                endDate: moment().subtract(1, 'days')
            }
        }
    }
  },  
  methods: {
    rangeSelection: function(e){
        this.endDate = this.rangeOptions[e.currentTarget.value].endDate;
        this.startDate = this.rangeOptions[e.currentTarget.value].startDate;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: I would suggest using `date-fns` instead of `moment`, since moment requires you to embed the entire library, and date-fns lets you import only the parts you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use [computed properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html):

```
computed: {
    endDate: function() {
      //determine endDate based on value of selectedRange
    },
    startDate: function() {
      //determine startDate based on value of selectedRange
    }
}
```

And [v-model](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-model) can be used to bind the value of the select list to that data property:

```
<select v-model="selectedRange">
```

Then use that property in the computed properties:

```
  computed: {
    endDate: function() {
      return this.rangeOptions[this.selectedRange].endDate;
    },
    startDate: function() {
      return this.rangeOptions[this.selectedRange].startDate;
    }
  }
```

With this approach there is no need to define the `rangeSelection` method and bind it to the onchange property.

`rangeOptions` could also be moved outside the component, and then the first key could be used to select the default value of `selectedRange` instead of hard coding it. See the snippet below.

```js
const rangeOptions = {
  last7Days: {
    display: 'Last 7 Days',
    startDate: moment().subtract(8, 'days'),
    endDate: moment().subtract(1, 'days')
  },
  lastWeek: {
    display: 'Last Week',
    startDate: moment().startOf('week').subtract(1, 'week'),
    endDate: moment().endOf('week').subtract(1, 'week')
  },
  last30days: {
    display: 'Last 30 days',
    startDate: moment().subtract(31, 'days'),
    endDate: moment().subtract(1, 'days')
  }
};
const form = new Vue({
  el: '#DateRangeChooser',
  data: () => {
    return {
      selectedRange: Object.keys(rangeOptions)[0],
      rangeOptions
    }
  },
  computed: {
    endDate: function() {
      return rangeOptions[this.selectedRange].endDate;
    },
    startDate: function() {
      return rangeOptions[this.selectedRange].startDate;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="DateRangeChooser">
  <select v-model="selectedRange">
    <option v-for="(option, key) in rangeOptions" :key="key" :value="key">
      {{option.display}}
    </option>
  </select>
  <div>Start: {{startDate.format('LL')}}</div>
  <div>End: {{endDate.format('LL')}}</div>
</div>
```

###Edit
[@blindman67](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/120556/blindman67) brought up an interesting point:

> Sorry my VUE knowledge is limited but I thought computed properties were cached. Could be a problem in some edge cases, eg time near midnight and user selects, then changes their mind waits till after midnight selects again?<sup>[1](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/206192/vue-component-over-complication/206213?noredirect=1#comment397843_206213)</sup>

That is true:

> ... **computed properties are cached based on their dependencies**<sup>[2](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Caching-vs-Methods)</sup>

if caching is an issue, then you may need to look at using a [watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) or just calculate the computed property each time instead of referencing values within `this.rangeOptions`.

<sup>1</sup><sub>https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/206192/vue-component-over-complication/206213?noredirect=1#comment397843_206213</sub>

<sup>2</sup><sub>https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Caching-vs-Methods</sub>

Comment: Sorry my VUE knowledge is limited but I thought computed properties were cached. Could be a problem in some edge cases, eg time near midnight and user selects, then changes their mind waits till after midnight selects again?

Comment: Good point - I amended my answer

Comment: Thank you both, this certainly leads me in the right direction!